# Angular Input should accept numbers only but first digit should not be zero

Tags: angular

My input should accept numbers only but not first digit as zero, in this directive regex can also be used , i tried but it is not working.

```
import { Directive ,ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNonZeroNumbersOnly]'
})
export class NonZeroNumbersOnlyDirective {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
        let initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
        this._el.nativeElement.style.background="yellow";
        console.log(this._el.nativeElement.value);
        if ( initalValue<1) {
          initalValue='';
        }
      }
 // @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
  //   const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
  //   this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
  //   if ( initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
  //     event.stopPropagation();
  //   }
  // }

}
```

```
HTML
<td class="unit">
          <input type="text" value={{billItem.quantity}} appNonZeroNumbersOnly />
</td>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a custom validator instead of a directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberOnly(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar))   
    {
       event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```